# LINQ error: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have following query:

```
var query = (from t1 in table1.Where(c => c.ServiceID == 2 && c.IsDeleted == 1)
             from t2 in table2.Where(c => c.RelServiceBonID == t1.RelServiceBonID && c.IsDeleted == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
             from t3 in table3.Where(c => c.BonID == t1.BonID && c.UserID == 8 && c.IsDeleted == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
             from t4 in table4.Where(c => c.BonID == t1.BonID && c.IsDeleted == 1)
             select new
             {                                  
                 t3.UserID, t2.SubServiceID,
             });

query.Dump();
```

When I run, I got the following error:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.

The `UserID` field is primary key and I can not set that as nullable!

How I can pass this error?

Comment: Well where is the null value coming from? Can you simplify the problem down as far as possible? My guess is that the problem is using `DefaultIfEmpty()`, but it's hard to tell for sure. (Do you definitely need to do left outer joins? If not, using proper joins would help...)

Comment: thanks for the answering and editing my post, If I comment t3.UserID line, is okay, but I need that in the result set ! I used `DefaultIfEmpty()`< because I need to implement `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: I have no error now, but the result is not correct !

Comment: I run that in SQL, I had more records as result. if I comment `t3.UserID` (in select section), I have no error and the result (as record count) is correct

Comment: Why do you need to select from table `t4`? This isn't contributing anything to the result set.

Comment: I removed some filed in `select section`, the real select set is too long. but all of them is okay, the problem is just for `UserID`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The UserID field is primary key and I can not set that as nullable

As hvd explained below, because you effectively have an outer join, `UserID` can still be null. Besides that, `SubServiceID` can also be null. Usually it helps to cast the culprit to a nullable type:

```
 select new
 {                                  
     UserID = (int?)t3.UserID, 
     SubServiceID = (int?)t2.SubServiceID
 });
```

Comment: No, not necessarily. The OP is effectively left-joining to `table3`, so it could still be the user ID that's returned as null from the database, because there's no record to retrieve the user ID from. That said, your approach is right but the syntax is wrong. You need to repeat the name (`new { UserID = (int?)t3.UserID, SubServiceID = (int?)t2.SubServiceID, }`) because the name can no longer be determined automatically.

Comment: Let me rephrase in an attempt to be clearer. Your C# code projects to an anonymous type with a `UserID` member of type `int`. The generated SQL returns a value `null` for that column. The CLR code then issues an error for that, because `int` cannot store `null`, and the way to fix that is to change that `int` to `int?` too.