# Inconsistent error in LINQ the null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I know there are lot of links related to this issue but my scenario is somewhat weird.
tbEHDepartments and tbEHAccesses tables are newly added hence reference of them in tbEHUsers table is null. As far my understanding and search NULL values in the column is the reason for error but works in scenario when ManagerID is null. I mean to say if i remove  grp1.DeptID from select query everything works properly even if ManagerId is null.

```
var data = from t in db.tbEHUsers.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join t3 in db.tbEHUsers.DefaultIfEmpty() on t.ManagerID equals t3.UserID into t2
           from grp in t2.DefaultIfEmpty()

           join d in db.tbEHDepartments.DefaultIfEmpty() on t.DeptID equals d.DeptID into t4
           from grp1 in t4.DefaultIfEmpty()

           join a in db.tbEHAccesses.DefaultIfEmpty() on t.AccessID equals a.AccessID into t5
           from grp2 in t5.DefaultIfEmpty()
           orderby t.FirstName
           select new { t.UserID, t.UserName, t.FirstName, t.LastName, t.Email, t.ManagerID, TeamLead = grp.FirstName + " " + grp.LastName, grp1.DeptID };//, grp1.DeptName, grp2.AccessID, AccessName=grp2.Name };

var dt = Utility.ToDataTable(data);
```

Comment: Is it exactly LINQ to SQL, or Entity Framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ error: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689869/linq-error-the-null-value-cannot-be-assigned-to-a-member-with-type-system-int32)

Comment: @Gert Thanks, DeptId=(int?)grp1.DeptID solved my problem

Comment: Hm, why do you use dead pseudo-ORM in late 2014? EF 6.1 is pretty good now days.

Answer (score 0):

Is ManagerID and USerID same data type? Is one of them Nullable hence "Int32?"  ?

Sometimes an error like that isn't thrown until data met in the database forces the problem.